# Why is this SQL in this PHP not working?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

My SQL in this PHP script cannot connect to my phpmyadmin-database on my XAMMP server:

```
<?php
//Shows every Error
error_reporting('E_All');
//used Host
define('MYSQL_HOST ', 'localhost');
//Name of SQL user
define('MYSQL_USER', 'root');
//Password of User
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '');
//Name of database
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'phpmodul');
?>

<?php
$db_link = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);
if ($db_link)
{
    echo 'Connection OK:', print_r($db_link);
}
else
{
    die('No connection: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

When I execute it, it just prints `No connection: php_network_getadressinfo failed: The Host is unkown.`
I am using PHP version 5.2.0 and XAMPP version 5.6.28

**Edit1** Changed mysqli_* to mysql_*

Comment: Follow a tutorial. When that fails, then get in touch.

Comment: Don't mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: do you even have `mysqli` extension enabled?

Comment: I have changed it to mysql, but it still doesn't work

Comment: please run `phpinfo();` and see if you have mysqli enabled.

Comment: mysqli is enabled

Comment: try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: That's silly, `mysql_*` has been deprecated for a long time already and now you have invalidated your sql even more as you don't have a database selected. Just get the error that `mysqli` generates.

Comment: the database is called 'phpmodul'

Comment: Also, the `E_ALL` in `error_reporting()` is a constant that represents an integer, so the quotes in your `error_reporting('E_All');` should be removed. The actual issue is because you have a space in your definition of `MYSQL_HOST` - remove that.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? 
Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)
 - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which.

Comment: before you comment, I have already solved the problem in an answer below.

Comment: `mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE)` that was the first reason why it failed you. mysql_connect only uses 3 arguments as opposed to mysqli_connect that uses 4. Next time, read the manuals; it would have avoided this question entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phpmodul");

if (mysqli_connect_error())
  {
      echo "Connection not possible: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else
  {
      echo "Connection succsessfully established.";
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dear I get you problem,

Please Remove Space From

```
define('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');
```

OR Replace line

```
define('MYSQL_HOST ', 'localhost');
```

TO

```
define('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: Only Remove space, Your code work fine :)
Hope u got it :) Enjoy :)